# Android listview doubles items when closed and opened in the emulator

Tags: android, listview

When I close and open the app in emulator the elements in the listview double each time...
While debugging I checked the list has element count as it is supposed to be.
but on the view it is doubled?

Comment: may you please post your code?

Comment: I was adding twice but in the debug checking before I was adding it