# Why my ListView automatically add another listview when i close the application and reopen it?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722566/android-listview-doubles-items-when-closed-and-opened-in-the-emulator) but there's no answer.

Could anyone explain why this thing happened?
How this event triggered?
How to resolve it?

After my observation to my listview my LayoutInflater is the cause of adding my multiple header and footer.. how can i stop it adding the item or reset my LayoutInflater?

> Here is my Code in filling items from the ListView when onResume triggered

```
    public void fillListViewOR(List<HashMap<String, String>> list)
    {
        String[] from = { 
                "textViewModeOfPaymentCheckValue",
                "textViewBankNameCheckIssued",
                "textViewCheckNumber",
                "textViewCheckDateValue",
        "textViewModeOfPayCheckValue"};
        int[] to = { R.id.textViewModeOfPaymentCheckValue,
                R.id.textViewBankNameCheckIssued,
                R.id.textViewCheckNumValue,
                R.id.textViewCheckDateValue,
                R.id.textViewModeOfPayCheckValue};

        String[] from2 = { 
                "textViewModeOfPaymentCheckValue",
                "textViewBankNameCheckIssued",
                "textViewCheckNumber",
                "textViewCheckDate",
                "textViewModeOfPayCheckValue"};
        int[] to2 = { R.id.textViewModeOfPaymentCheckValue,
                R.id.textViewBankNameCheckIssued,
                R.id.textViewCheckNumber,
                R.id.textViewCheckDate,
                R.id.textViewModeOfPayCheckValue};


        adapterListView = new SpecialAdapter(getBaseContext(),list,R.layout.listview_layout,from2,to2);
        adapterListView.notifyDataSetChanged();

        headerViewOR = ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.jpos_or_header, null, false);
        //bodyView = ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.listview_layout, null, false);
        footerViewOR = ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.jpos_or_footer, null, false);   

        lv.addHeaderView(headerViewOR);
        lv.addFooterView(footerViewOR);
        lv.setAdapter(adapterListView);

    ----------------------
    --- and so on from the view items of the header and footer

}
```

> Here is my Special Adapter

```
public class SpecialAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    public static TextView tv;
    private int[] colors = new int[] { 0xffcccccc , 0xffffffff };
    private int[] colors2 = new int[] { 0xffffffff , 0xff000000 }; 
   // Context context;
    public SpecialAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> items, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, items, resource, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
      int colorPos = position % colors.length;
      view.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
      //TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewModAmountCheck);
      //textView.setText("AlvinTest");
      return view;
    }


    public View getView2(Context context, int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);//get your layout inflator;

//LayoutInflater inf = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_layout, null);
        }
        LinearLayout yyy = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linearCheckDate);
        yyy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return convertView;
    }

    public View getViewChild(Context context, int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);//get your layout inflator;
       // LayoutInflater inf = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_layout, null);
        }
        LinearLayout yyy = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linearCheckDate);
        yyy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return convertView;
    }




    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){    
        int getIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("Name");
        String empname = cursor.getString(getIndex);
        tv = (TextView) view;
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tv.setText(empname);
        if(empname.equals("Any String"))
        {                   
            tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(58, 58, 224));
            return true;
        }
        return false;           
    }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your code its difficult to say anything. Please, post your code.

Comment: i don't know what part of my code i will post... it was almost 4k lines of code -_- that's why i want to know what was the event triggered it and what part should i lookup

Comment: post those code snippet where you triggered the ListView.

Comment: can you post the constructor for your SpecialAdapter?

Comment: How are you generating the contents of the `list`? Are you adding items to it without `clear`ing its contents? The other possibility is the SpecialAdapter. Show us the constructor or show us how you populate its contents. I have a strong feeling the `list` contains duplicate items.

Comment: nope i instantiate my array list to reset it then i start adding items on the onResume.

Comment: sorry for the late reply it was lunch break here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**All of my ListView operation with the LayoutInflater codes must be place to `@onCreate` not in `@onResume` It's my mistake because i used wrong format of filling my ListView because i used this process from my previous operations of my Application.**

> Because when we close the application it retains the layout and it goes to the `@onResume`, `@onStart` after we reopen the application and it will not go to the `@onCreate` operation because it was already created. That's why i'm having multiple view of header and footer to my List View.

Answer (score 0):

I would try commenting out this line:

```
adapterListView.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I think it's causing your data to be processed twice.

Comment: i removed it but same thing happened

Comment: how are you creating the list that you pass into the *fillListViewOR* method?

Comment: all of the process started in onResume..it was an 3 dimensional array list... and i fetch it to satisfy the conditions from the fillListViewOR method

Comment: at the beginning of the method print out a log statement to see what size the list, perhaps it keeps growing inadvertently?

Comment: the size of the list item adapter in the same... my problem here is the Whole listview containing the item and header and footer view added again after closing the app and reopening it..

Comment: how can i reset the value of the view of my layout inflater this was the cause of having my multiple view of my listview..